# Dimming all layers other than the active in Altium

Tags: altium

I know single layer mode (shift + s) but it hides too much.

I really like highlight mode (right click on layer tab -> highlight, or ctrl+click on layer tab) where the all other layers are just slightly dimmed.
But when you switch layers it stays only on the layer you activated it. Also with shift+c it goes away and you need to activate it again.

Is there any option where all layers except the active one are displayed slightly dimmed (like in highlight mode)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different view configuration:

Use L to select layers

Go to transparency and select which layers you want to be transparent and which ones you don't.

This can be saved as a configuration.

Comment: Problem is as I said single layer mode hides too much, you can't see component outlines or courtyards because they're on different layers.